# Шифрование и дешифрование пароля

Tags: c#, windows, .net

Возникла необходимость использования пароля в приложении. Что лучше всего использовать для его шифровки и дешифровки в C#? Есть ли стоящие стандартные решения?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, шифрование и дешифрование данных по введённому пользователем ключу? Вот тут по идее должны быть примеры: [MSDN: Encrypting data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). А ещё обсуждается здесь: [en.SO: Encrypt and decrypt a string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2791259/276994).

Comment: Стоящее стандартное решение -- использование виндовой аутентификации (если она есть на машинах, конечно).

Answer (score 2):

Пароли, как правило, не шифруют, а просто хранят в виде хэша, например [md5](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), дабы никто с ними не мог ознакомиться.
При аутентификации, введённая последовательность хэшируется тем же алгоримом. Смысл в том что бы [сравнивать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C#.D0.91.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B8.D1.80.D1.83.D1.8E.D1.89.D0.B8.D0.B9.D1.81.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.85.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B0.D1.85) не пароли, а их хэши.

Answer (score 2):

В состав .NET Framework входят криптографические средства, они расположены в пространстве имен [System.Security.Cryptography](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/System.Security.Cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx).

Чтобы не хранить пароль в открытом виде вы можете сохранять его MD5-хэш. Вычислить его можно с помощью [MD5CryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx). В статье по ссылке есть пример вычисления хэша.

При сохранении пароля вычисляйте хэш, и сохраняйте его вместо пароля. В момент аутентификации юзера, вновь вычисляйте хэш и сравнивайте с хранящимся в бд значением, если хэши совпадают, значит пароль верный.